# Can't translate some Javascript code I need for my C# App

Tags: c#, google-maps, android-appwidget

I'm trying to build a simple app that locates restaurants nearby but I am kinda lost since I can't find how to translate this piece of code from the Google guide to C# and implement it into my app since I cannot find PlacesService any way I try.

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
var place = results[i];
createMarker(results[i]);
}
}
}
```

Chat Conversation End

Comment: check Google Maps API for .NET https://gmaps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: [GoogleMapsAPI nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleMapsApi/0.52.0)

It's a 'Google Maps Web Services API wrapper for .NET'

Here is a [GitHub page](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps) where you can find some examples, but this library is pretty well documented.

Comment: Just like MaKCbIMKo said, you can't translate it because that example uses a library written for javascript. You need an equivalent library for .NET if it exists. So this link above might be what you need.